openSUSE Tumbleweed, hibernation works only once, freezing on the second time
Since a few days, when I try to hibernate my system, it works one time, but when I try it the second time, my system freezes. To be specific: When start hibernation, my lockscreen gets shown briefly, then my monitor turns off. After 30 seconds or so, it turns back on, showing the lockscreen again. Normally, or when I hibernate for the first time, the system shuts down after that and the hibernation process is successfully finished. On the second time, the system freezes, the only way out of this is to manually shut the system down. I've looked into journalctl and the output I get when hibernating for the first time is:
Okt 07 16:29:13 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd[1]: Starting System Hibernate...
Okt 07 16:29:13 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[5029]: User sessions remain unfrozen (add $SYSTEMD_SLEEP_FREEZE_USER_SESSIONS=1 to override),
Okt 07 16:29:13 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[5029]: relying on kernel to perform the freeze.
Okt 07 16:29:13 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[5029]: This is a temporary downstream workaround for https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/33083.
Okt 07 16:29:13 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[5031]: INFO: running /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/grub2.sleep for hibernate
Okt 07 16:29:13 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[5031]: INFO: Running prepare-grub ..
Okt 07 16:29:14 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[5031]:   running kernel is grub menu entry openSUSE Tumbleweed (vmlinuz-6.11.0-1-default)
Okt 07 16:29:14 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[5031]:   preparing boot-loader: selecting entry openSUSE Tumbleweed, kernel /boot/6.11.0-1-default
Okt 07 16:29:14 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[5031]:   running /usr/sbin/grub2-once "openSUSE Tumbleweed"
Okt 07 16:29:14 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[5031]:     time needed for sync: 0.0 seconds, time needed for grub: 0.1 seconds.
Okt 07 16:29:14 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[5031]: INFO: Done.
Okt 07 16:29:14 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[5029]: Performing sleep operation 'hibernate'...
Okt 07 16:29:14 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de kernel: PM: hibernation: hibernation entry
Okt 07 16:29:14 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de PackageKit[3333]: get-updates transaction /2_bebcadea from uid 1000 finished with success after 1381ms
Okt 07 16:31:09 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.005 seconds

As you can see, the last entry is two seconds behind the second last one. So I assume that the last entry is the first log of the boot of the successfully hibernated system. So, the two last entries before shutting down are:
Okt 07 16:29:14 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de kernel: PM: hibernation: hibernation entry
Okt 07 16:29:14 p200300eb272397192edf2565a19aec26.dip0.t-ipconnect.de PackageKit[3333]: get-updates transaction /2_bebcadea from uid 1000 finished with success after 1381ms

When I tried to hibernate a second time, the journalctl output is:
Okt 07 16:31:29 p200300eb27239719b3907f64d0c2f2eb.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd[1]: Starting System Hibernate...
Okt 07 16:31:29 p200300eb27239719b3907f64d0c2f2eb.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[6624]: User sessions remain unfrozen (add $SYSTEMD_SLEEP_FREEZE_USER_SESSIONS=1 to override),
Okt 07 16:31:29 p200300eb27239719b3907f64d0c2f2eb.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[6624]: relying on kernel to perform the freeze.
Okt 07 16:31:29 p200300eb27239719b3907f64d0c2f2eb.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[6624]: This is a temporary downstream workaround for https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/33083.
Okt 07 16:31:29 p200300eb27239719b3907f64d0c2f2eb.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[6627]: INFO: running /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/grub2.sleep for hibernate
Okt 07 16:31:29 p200300eb27239719b3907f64d0c2f2eb.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[6627]: INFO: Running prepare-grub ..
Okt 07 16:31:29 p200300eb27239719b3907f64d0c2f2eb.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[6627]:   running kernel is grub menu entry openSUSE Tumbleweed (vmlinuz-6.11.0-1-default)
Okt 07 16:31:29 p200300eb27239719b3907f64d0c2f2eb.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[6627]:   preparing boot-loader: selecting entry openSUSE Tumbleweed, kernel /boot/6.11.0-1-default
Okt 07 16:31:29 p200300eb27239719b3907f64d0c2f2eb.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[6627]:   running /usr/sbin/grub2-once "openSUSE Tumbleweed"
Okt 07 16:31:30 p200300eb27239719b3907f64d0c2f2eb.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[6627]:     time needed for sync: 0.0 seconds, time needed for grub: 0.1 seconds.
Okt 07 16:31:30 p200300eb27239719b3907f64d0c2f2eb.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[6627]: INFO: Done.
Okt 07 16:31:30 p200300eb27239719b3907f64d0c2f2eb.dip0.t-ipconnect.de systemd-sleep[6624]: Performing sleep operation 'hibernate'...
Okt 07 16:31:30 p200300eb27239719b3907f64d0c2f2eb.dip0.t-ipconnect.de kernel: PM: hibernation: hibernation entry

Now, the last entry is
Okt 07 16:31:30 p200300eb27239719b3907f64d0c2f2eb.dip0.t-ipconnect.de kernel: PM: hibernation: hibernation entry

So, the last entry before the first hibernation isn't there. Unfortunately, I have no clue what these entries mean.
Can anyone give me a hand? It would be really appreciated.
My system specs:
Operating System: openSUSE Tumbleweed 20241006
KDE Plasma Version: 6.1.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.6.0
Qt Version: 6.7.3
Kernel Version: 6.11.0-1-default (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 16 × AMD Ryzen 7 7800X3D 8-Core Processor
Memory: 30,5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon RX 7900 XT
Manufacturer: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
Product Name: MS-7E24
System Version: 1.0

